# WPF - Get file name while using PrintDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, savefiledialog

I use PrintDialog to print a particular control.

I wanted to know is there a way to know what file name the user chose as can be done with
SaveFileDialog?

```
var pd = new PrintDialog();
if (pd.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
{
    pd.PrintVisual(bc, "Print control");
}
```

Comment: *the user chose* -- does user need choose something to print?

Comment: The user can save it to PDF

Comment: i searched but didn't find related properties. can you explain why getting the name is necessary?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to open a print window for the user (for my control).
If he wants to print to PDF then he saves it on his computer somewhere, and I want to open the file for him immediately after saving.
But to open the file for him I need to know the path

Comment: i don't see the point of openning the file for him. you can have a customized dialog, if user select pdf, you just print to pdf without printdialog, so the filename under your control.